# asp.net xpath: select only certain attributes

Tags: asp.net, xpath, attributes

I have a GridView populated from an xml file, which has the following structure:

```
<menu>
  <item id="1" name="home" page="default.aspx">
     *{...some stuff...}*
  <item>
  <item id="2" name="content" page="content.aspx">
     *{...some stuff...}*
  <item>
  <item id="3" name="user" page="user.aspx">
     *{...some stuff...}*
  <item>
<menu>
```

As you can reckon, it's the menu of my application.

If i just associate that file to an xmldatasource and then to a GridView, it shows (correctly) a grid like this:

> **id  name     page**
>
> 1   home     default.aspx
>
> 2   content  content.aspx
>
> 3   user     user.aspx3   user     user.aspx

How do I set the xPath query to only show name attribute/field?

I've tried those:

1. menu/item@name
2. menu/@name
3. //@name

but didn't work

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation of the problem and a complete solution. :)

Comment: I think this is not an XPath question but MS Databinding question. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479341.aspx : it looks like you need to set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` attribute of `asp:GridView` element, and then use `Columns` and `asp:BoundField` childs.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a GridView populated from an
>   xml file, which has the following
>   structure:
>
> ```
> <menu> 
>   <item id="1" name="home" page="default.aspx"> 
>      *{...some stuff...}* 
>   <item> 
>   <item id="2" name="content" page="content.aspx"> 
>      *{...some stuff...}* 
>   <item> 
>   <item id="3" name="user" page="user.aspx"> 
>      *{...some stuff...}* 
>   <item> 
> <menu>
> ```

**This is not a well-formed XML file** -- an ending tag must have the sintax `</tag>` and there are no ending tags at all in the above text.

> How do I set the xPath query to only
>   show name attribute/field?
>
> > I've tried those:
>
> 1. menu/item@name
> 2. menu/@name
> 3. //@name

1. is syntactically invalid: location steps must start with the `/` character and there is no `/` character between `item` and `@name`.
2. is syntactically valid but is asking to select all `name` attributes of all `menu` elements that are children of the current node. Unfortunately, `menu` has no `name` attributes.
3. should select nodes, but given the text above isn't at all a well-formed XML document, this explains the negative result. Also, this selects all `name` attributes in the whole document, regardles on which element they are -- this is not exactly what you want, regardless of the fact that on a wellformed document of this type this might select the nodes you want.

**Solution**:

**Step1:** Correct your XML document:

```
<menu>
  <item id="1" name="home" page="default.aspx">
     *{...some stuff...}*
  </item>
  <item id="2" name="content" page="content.aspx">
     *{...some stuff...}*
  </item>
  <item id="3" name="user" page="user.aspx">
     *{...some stuff...}*
  </item>
</menu>
```

**Step2**: Use one of the following XPath expressions (there are even more that would select the wanted nodes):

```
/menu/item/@name
```

or

```
/*/item/@name
```

or

```
/*/*/@name
```

or

```
//@name
```

Comment: about the xml: off course it's not well formed as i write it down from scratch, it actually is in my project (the xml is even more complex, i only mention a simplied version of it). Thanks anyway, i'll try those queries and i'll let you know ;)